# unable to update redux state using react update addon

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

The below is my reducer state from console.log

```
state:{getMessagesRequest: false,projects:[]}
```

the projects array has objects of the below structure

```
{messages:Array[0],userid:'foo',username:'bar'}
```

The reducer pushes message objects into the messages array using the below case:

```
  case GET_PROJECT_MESSAGES_SUCCESS:
      console.log('GET_PROJECT_MESSAGES_SUCCESS invoked: ',action)
      let target = state.projects.findIndex((project) => {
          return project.project_id == action.project_id
        })
    action.data.map((message) => {
      console.log('TARGET IS : ',target)
      console.log('MESSSAGE IS: ',message)
      return update(state,{
        projects:{
          [target]:{
            messages:{
              $push:[message]
            }
          }
        }
      })
    })
```

console.log shows a valid value for target (target=0) and message (which is an object)

but the reducer shows the below error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined
```

which suggests that its breaking on [target] .. but target has the right value so i'm unsure where else the problem might be.

i have an additional reducer pretty much doing a similar thing , but i only have one message object to push to the project array . the reducer works in this case:

```
   case NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE: //use parseInt instead of ==
      target = state.projects.findIndex((project) => {
        return project.project_id == action.data.projectid
      })
      return update(state,{
        projects:{
          [target]:{
            messages:{
              $push:[action.data]
            }
          }
        }
      })
```

`action.data` is an object. the first reducer deals with an array of objects - hence the map function.

Where could the problem be?

**update** : its quite weird but the second reducer `NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE` also gets invoked once the execution of `GET_PROJECT_MESSAGES_SUCCESS` is done. the error is sent by the new_chat reducer . the state still isnt getting updated. Could it be a problem due to multiple returns from the first reducer?(since i'm looping over the objects?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wound up doing this instead of looping through the array

```
  return update(state,{
      projects:{
        [target]:{
          messages:{
            $set:action.data
          }
        }
      }
    })
```